# How does the ParseFromArray function work in C++ and how can it be used to read a binary file into a protobuf?

Tags: c++, function, parsing, protocol-buffers, binaryfiles

I am a little unsure about how exactly the ParseFromArray(...) function in C++ works. What does it do exactly and how can it be used property? For example, if I am trying to read a binary file into a protobuf how can I do it using ParseFromArray(...). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally if you want to parse a protobuf from a file, you would make sure you opened the file in binary mode and then call `ParseFromIstream`.

`ParseFromArray` and `ParseFromString` (which differ only in the datatype of their argument) are used to parse protobufs which are already in memory. You might want to do that if the protobuf is only a part of the file, and you know how to extract the bytes. If you extract (or read) the bytes as a `std::string`, you could use `ParseFromString`, but most of the time you will be using [`std::istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read binary files, and that function reads data into a buffer (which is an array of `char`). You would then call `ParseFromArray` with the starting address of the buffer (cast to `void*`) and its length.